# Storing a string into a permenant variable issue

Tags: java, android, string, settext

I'am trying to store a string from a variable (NumberString) to another variable (PermenantString)
When the string is entered in to PermenantString, it should be stored permenantly in that variable, until the app is deleted or i specifically create a button to clear that PermenantString variable.

MainAvtivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final String PermenantString= "";
```

verified.class

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verified);

        Button VerifyCompleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.VerifyCompleteButton);

        VerifyCompleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
           public void onClick(View view) 
           {    

             String NumberString;
             String PermenantString;
             //TextView NUMView;

             TextView NUMView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NUMView);

             Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

             NumberString= bundle.getString("NumberString");
             PermenantString = bundle.getString("PermenantString");


            PermenantString= NumberString.toString();
             //set String PermenantString= ""; permenantly

            NUMView.setText(PermenantString);
             //
           } 



           });
```

Comment: How permanent is "permanent"? Do you have other activities in your app?

Answer (score 2):

You should use preferences or sqlite to store the data. Check the storage options @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Example:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
```

Then

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("key", stringvalue);
editor.commit();
```

Then to get

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String value = settings.getString("key","defaultstring");
```

Comment: I dont think its worth the hassle as its only one variable that i need to permenanly store a string in. Originally when the app is downloaded the Variable is empty then the user will enter one string that will be permenantly stored until the app is deleted.

Comment: @user3247335 use preferences it will help. Sqlite may work but its not worth for storing a string variable value.

Comment: @user3247335 what do you mean by app is deleted you mean uninstalled??

Comment: @user3247335 then use shared preferences. It can be used to store string value and there is example in the link i posted

Comment: @Raghunandan : You forgot to use `commit()` in your example of putting the string into the preferences.

Comment: @Squonk thanks for pointing it out. and the key also was not matching. edited

Answer (score 1):

Note that variables are stored in volatile RAM memory. By volatile, I mean that the value is stored only as long as your app is running. This is the very opposite of the permanence that you seem to want.

In order to save a variable that will persist after your app is destroyed, you *must* use some storage mechanism such as `SharedPreferences` or a SQLite database. For more information, you should read [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in the Android Developer Guides.